# Integrating $y'(x)y''(x)$ with respect to $x$

Tags: integration, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'm having trouble with integrating $y'y''$, because I can think of two different answers that seem correct to me.

1)  $$y''y' = y'' \frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$y''y'dx = y''dy $$
$$\int y''y'dx = y' + C$$

2) $$y''y' = \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{1}{2} (y')^2)$$
So $$\int y''y'dx = (\frac{1}{2} (y')^2)$$

These answers seem quite different, but I can figure out which is correct (assuming one is) and why the other would be incorrect.

Comment: $\int y''dy\neq y'+C$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the other would be incorrect?

This is because $\int y''(x)~dy \neq y'(x)+C$. However, it is true that:
$$\int y''(x)~dx=y'(x)+C$$

---

> Which is correct?

The second result you obtained is correct (Except you forgot the arbitrary constant). One may easily see this by substituting:
$$u=y'(x) \implies du=y''(x)~dx$$
This gives:
$$\int u~du=\frac{1}{2}u^2+C=\frac{1}{2}(y'(x))^2+C$$

Comment: Thank you, I see that now. I was substituting incorrectly on the first equation.

Answer (score 5):

You can also go by parts naively taking your first expression: 
$$
\int y'(x)y''(x)dx=(y'(x))^2-\int y'(x)y''(x)dx\implies 2\int y'(x)y''(x)dx=(y'(x))^2\implies \int y'(x)y''(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}(y'(x))^2+c
$$

Comment: @projectilemotion aww thank you! I'll upvote yours in any event :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to projectilemotion's answer, integration by parts may make the calculation easier.
\begin{align*}
\int y'(x)y''(x)dx = y'(x)^2+c - \int y''(x)y'(x) dx
\end{align*}

Comment: This is a nice answer, but unfortunately @qbert was $1$ minute $8$ seconds faster than you.